# How to hide Crosstab Column Header in XLS report - Crosstab and Subreport in Summary Band

Tags: java, jasper-reports, xls, crosstab

In report I have crosstab and one subreport, both in Summary Band.

Problem is repeating of Crosstab column header in XLS report.
(Want to have only one column header)

I've tried some tricks, but nothing is good enough.

1) If uncheck Crosstab Properties - Repeat Column Header result is ok but than don't have headers in HTML and PDF, it is not ok.

2) If `IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION = true` only for XLS, it is OK but for some reason subreport is not printing! (this is the biggest problem,don't know why?)

3) Properties like this are not applicable on CROSSTAB

```
result.put("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1", "pageHeader");
result.put("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2", "pageFooter");
result.put("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.3", "columnHeader");
result.put("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1", "columnHeader");
result.put("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2", "pageHeader");
```

4) I have tried to put main page report page height to some big number like 999999 but still subreport is not printing if `IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION = true`

Is there some property for crosstab that can be set from Java, depending on output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer to my own question.

After many attempts, due to a lack of time, I made a new report for XLS output format.
*(Now I have two nearly same report, one for PDF and HTML, and other for XLS output format)*

In report I have **unchecked Crosstab Properties - Repeat Column Header**.

The downside of this is maintenance, but for now this is the only solution.